# Let user view file only once with PHP

Tags: php, file, download

Got a request that I'm not even sure is feasible:  The plan is to only allow users to see a PDF in their browser after they have filled out a form.

I can't think of a way to redirect to a PDF in browser in a way that makes it viewable only once.

The best thing I can think of is forcing a download of the PDF after they submit the form.

Comment: you mean show the PDF only once and that even if your form has been filled up ?

Comment: From a technical standpoint, there's little difference between "view" and "download". Your server can send the file once (no matter the purpose) but you can't prevent the client from storing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "only once" ?

You can redirect to the URL linking to that PDF once the form is completed.
Or, you can reload the page (or part of it) with an appropriate link to that PDF file.

To do things "once" you either recognize the user using [PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) (but it's good only until the user closes the connection to your server) or you could persist the fact that the current user is not to receive the PDF again by writing a record in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is pretty easy:

- for each download you wish to allow, create a hash and store it in a table
- in download.php, evaluate that hash:

  - if it's not there, return a 501 or 503
  - if it's there, set your mime type to application/pdf and return the contents of the file